# Ground problems in kitchen

Tags: ac, ground, grounding

i have had some trouble in my kitchen recently about some tingling stingy feeling while touching the kitchen sink. and stove metal.

my toughts is that here is some ground problems but I could not quite locate the problems.

recently I purchased some new LED light to use under the kitchen ventilator, so a few nights I can se these LED's very dim... when I investigated further, this ventilator is entirely off, but I can still change the position of the fan speed.

it was now set to 0, this is when the LED shows as very dim, if I change it to position 1 - 2 or 3 the LED light dissappears, however in between the steps (middle of 1 - 2 and or 2 - 3) this LED shows as dim again until i push it over to either 1 - 2 or 3.

if I again set it to position 0 (off)  the lights dim again

is the ventilator defective or is the problem more severe ?

would also like to know how to use a multimeter to check this

Comment: This sounds more like a diy.stackexchange.com question.

Comment: Sounds more like call someone that knows what they're doing to me.

Comment: @Kellenjb - Unless you know what you are doing this sounds like a professional job. So it's not really a question for DIY